# Dart equivalent of Pjax

Tags: dart, dart-html

Pjax loads an html page via ajax into a div, see 
http://pjax.herokuapp.com/
and 
https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/tree/heroku

What would be the equivalent mechanism in pure dart to load html into a div from a file that would work for all modern browsers? (doesn't matter if it's via GET, POST, AJAX, etc)

Comment: You can just make a HTTP request and insert the received text into the dom. There are enough examples for both things here on SO. You can't load Dart code this way though. You can load Dart code into an isolate but this code doesn't have access to the dom.

Comment: That sounds awesome, thanks Gunter! I'll just load all the dart code and css on index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  HttpRequest.getString('page.html').then((html){
    querySelector("#content").children.clear();
    querySelector('#content').appendHtml(html);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Elements` [`appendHTML`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Element#id_appendHtml) to insert HTML from a string.